# Summarizing meteorological data with the help of a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a meteorological data set with daily precipitation values for 120 years. I would like to prepare this in such a way that I have monthly average values for 4 climate periods at the end. Example: Average precipitation January, February, March, ... for period 1981 - 2010, average precipitation January, February, March, ... for period 2011 - 2040 and so on.
Data set looks like this (is available as csv file, read in as pandas dataframe):

```
       year  month  day  lon  lat      value
0      1981      1    1    0    0   0.522592
1      1981      1    2    0    0   2.692495
2      1981      1    3    0    0   0.556698
3      1981      1    4    0    0   0.000000
4      1981      1    5    0    0   0.000000
...     ...    ...  ...  ...  ...        ...
43824  2100     12   27    0    0   0.000000
43825  2100     12   28    0    0   0.185120
43826  2100     12   29    0    0  10.252080
43827  2100     12   30    0    0  13.389290
43828  2100     12   31    0    0   3.523566
```

Here my code until now:

```
csv_path = r'filepath.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, delimiter = ';')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])

years = pd.date_range('1981-01-01', periods = 6, freq = '30YS').strftime('%Y')
labels = [f'{a}-{b}' for a, b in zip(years, years[1:])]

(df.assign(period = pd.cut(df['year'], bins = years.astype(int), labels = labels, right = False)).groupby(df[['year', 'month']].dt.to_period('M')).agg({'period': 'first', 'value': 'sum'}).groupby('period')['value'].mean())
```

The best way is probably to write a loop that iterates over all months and the 4 30-year periods, but unfortunately I can't get this to work. Does anyone have any tips?
Expected Output:

```
     Month  Average
0  January       20
1  Febuary       21
2    March       19
3    April       18
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the total value per month and then the average per periods 30 years, you need to use a double `groupby`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])

years = pd.date_range('1981-01-01', periods=6, freq='30YS').strftime('%Y')
labels = [f'{a}-{b}' for a,b in zip(years, years[1:])]

(df
 .assign(period=pd.cut(df['year'], bins=years.astype(int), labels=labels, right=False))
 .groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('M')).agg({'period':'first', 'value': 'sum'})
 .groupby('period')['value'].mean()
)
```

output:

```
period
1981-2011     3.771785
2011-2041          NaN
2041-2071          NaN
2071-2101    27.350056
2101-2131          NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

##### older answer

The expected output is not fully clear, but if you want average precipitation per quarter per year:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q')
df.groupby('quarter')['value'].mean()
```

output:

```
quarter
1981Q1    0.754357
2100Q4    5.470011
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

or per quarter globally:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df['quarter'] = df['date'].dt.quarter
df.groupby('quarter')['value'].mean()
```

output:

```
quarter
1    0.754357
4    5.470011
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

*NB. you can do the same for other periods. For months use `to_period('M')` / `.dt.month`*

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df['period'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('M')
df.groupby('period')['value'].mean()
```

output:

```
period
1981-01    0.754357
2100-12    5.470011
Freq: M, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why not use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) eg. `resample(...).mean()` ?

Comment: @user12932966 you can, but the original dataset seems to have the date as column, this avoid setting the index. Also resample works differently as it will fill missing values and use the first day of month by default. I'll add a note

Comment: @mozway Regarding the output: I would first like to have average monthly precipitation values over all years. These are then to be averaged again over four 30-year periods, so that I then have average monthly precipitation values over four 30-year periods. Is this explained in an understandable way?

Comment: @thomas.f can you provide the explicit expected output for clarity?

Comment: @mozway I have worked on my question and presented the expected output (numbers just made up). I want such a table (or similar) for four periods so that I can then plot them (1981 - 2010, 2011 - 2040, 2041 - 2070 and 2071 - 2100).

Comment: In terms of the averages, do you really want to average on several levels (first by month, then year, then 3 decades), or do you want to directly get the average per 3 decades? This might give different results as the mean of a mean is not necessarily the mean of all elements (depends on group size)

Comment: @mozway I want to sum the daily precipitation to monthly precipitation and then average the monthly precipitation total over the 30 year periods. Maybe a little mispronounced earlier... ;)

Comment: @thomas.f check if the update is what you want

Comment: @mozway I think it's going in the right direction. But now I have the problem in the line with the first 'groupby()'. Here 'date' somehow doesn't work (it shows me only KeyError: 'date'..)

Comment: This was coming from your code, I added it for clarity ;)

Comment: Or you can group by year+month instead

Comment: @mozway I already had the first line, but somehow it still doesn't work....
If I exchange 'date' with 'year', 'month' at the first groupby, I get the same error as before, only this time with 'KeyError: year'. I really don't know what's wrong...

Comment: @mozway Ahhhh I removed line 2 and 3 from my code, which resulted in the error not being displayed anymore. However, I now have the following new error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'....

Comment: I don't think you're running my exact code. Please provide a minimal reproducible input so that we can both test the same thing ;)

Comment: @mozway okay, I have edited my question and put the current code. What is the best way to give the file to you?